# How to create a search result page using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I was asked to create a companies search on our database using phone number or a name. The problem is they both are in the same text box like so:

```
<input type="text" name = "nameOrPhone" />
```

So I need to use this parameter to make the search look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '$nameOrPhone%' OR phone LIKE $nameOrPhone%
```

I get a syntax error from MySql.

The problem is i want to use this to search in two columns. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Also take a look at the FULLTEXT search capability in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the highlighting it is showing your problem. You forgot to put quotes around it.
This is what you are probably looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '$nameOrPhone%' OR phone LIKE '$nameOrPhone%'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that was it i totally missed that or maybe cuz i thought that the phone wasn't supposed to be a string this is why i didn't put it thank you

Comment: It definitly is you should check out my edit too because that might cause a new problem. ;)